# Error: Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, typescript, string

I have a mini project that I need to make a simple calculator with a history. In a part of this project, it should be deleted if one of the history items is clicked, but I got an error while making this. Do you have a solution to solve this error and a theory? About my solution to delete items you have

> Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

```js
let text: string = "";
const historyArrey: Array<String> = [];
let equal = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-blue");

equal[0].addEventListener("click", () => {
    let response = eval(text);
    let historyBox = document.getElementById("history");

    (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('screen')).value = response;

    historyArrey.push(text + "=" + response);
    console.log(historyArrey);

    if (historyBox) {
        historyBox.innerHTML = historyArrey.map((i) => {//error
            return "<p onclick='removeItem()'>" + { i } + "</p>"
        });
        historyArrey.join("<br/>")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

Your `join` here:

```
historyBox.innerHTML = historyArrey.map((i) => {
  return "<p onclick='removeItem()'>" + { i } + "</p>"
});
historyArrey.join("<br/>")
```

does nothing.

### Solution

You have to `join` the array before assigning

```
historyBox.innerHTML = historyArrey.map((i) => {
  return "<p onclick='removeItem()'>" + { i } + "</p>"
}).join("<br/>");
```